# Donut project: Extrude producing blocky icing

Tags: modeling

I am following Blender Guru on Youtube step by step, but seem to get hung up on this part, even after restarting the project from scratch several times.  I'm not sure what I'm missing but his extrude seems to be nice and fat and rounded off by default, but mine is totally squared off.  I"m obviously missing something fundamental but for the life of me I'm not catching it when he says/does it.

I applied the additional subdivision as he does as well, and solidify settings were the same.

Edited to provide more detail.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I've also tried rounding the edge first, and got this:
[image: Image 3]

And here's what his looks like:

[image: his]

Comment: I haven't seen that tutorial but did make a doughnut some time back.  I didn't extrude the icing, rather used proportional edit which allows you to move a single vertice up or down, and those vertices nearby will follow it, but proportionally. (graduated fashion)  Some subdivision beforehand would likely be required. You end up with a nicely curved edge.  To see the radius of influence the P/Edit will have, select the vertice first then press G (grab) and use the page up/down numpad keys to see and change the size of the influence.  Hope that helps...

Comment: have you given a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object? It looks like not...